# Is there a way to do early-stopping and cross validation in CNTK?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, deep-learning, cross-validation, cntk

As asked in the title, i would like to know if it is possible to make a model early-stop the epochs during training when the error is reduced enough, so i can avoid overfitting and guessing the right number of epochs at each call.

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/How-do-I-Evaluate-Models-in-BrainScript) is the only thing i have found in the official documentation but it is tobe used in brainscript, and i don't know a single thing about it. I'm using Python 3.6 with CNTK 2.6.

Also, is there a way to perform cross validation in a CNTK CNN?? How could this be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **CrossValidationConfig** class tells CNTK to periodically evaluate the model on a validation data set, and then **call a user-specified callback function**, which then can be used to update the learning rate or to return **False** to indicate **early stopping**.

For examples on how to implement early stopping:

1. `test_session_cv_callback_early_exit function` [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/bindings/python/cntk/train/tests/training_session_test.py)
2. **Source code for cntk.train.training_session** [here](https://www.cntk.ai/pythondocs/_modules/cntk/train/training_session.html).

Comment: Thank you!! Could you please provide an example of how to set up the CrossValidationConfig class ??

Comment: @Miguel 2488 You may find something [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/bindings/python/cntk/train/tests/training_session_test.py). Specially the **test_session_cv_callback_early_exit** function.

Comment: Thank you!! I will take a look carefully at that :)

Comment: @Miguel 2488 Check also **Source code for cntk.train.training_session** [here](https://www.cntk.ai/pythondocs/_modules/cntk/train/training_session.html). Seems to have an example of how to implement early stopping.

Comment: Thank you again @agcala, this is more or less what i was looking for. It helped :)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any native implementation for early stopping in cntk. For cross validation you can look up [CrossValidationConfig](https://www.cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk.train.training_session.html#cntk.train.training_session.CrossValidationConfig)

Comment: Hi @snowflake, thank you for your answer :) damn, you said no native implementation... but is there a workaround or some hand made possible way to do it?

Comment: So usually, i would append the result of a separate evaluation of the test set on to a list and calculate when i need to stop separately.

Comment: @ Miguel 2488 You can use the CrossValidationConfig class to perform early stopping. Read my answer.